# CASE statement in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a procedure in which the below condition is to be written in a `WHERE` clause. How do I do that using `CASE`, or something like it?

```
IF (@itemId IS NOT NULL)
  dataId = @itemid
```

Comment: Is that really `itemid` and not `@itemId` in the second line?

Comment: sorry it should be @itemId.forgot to add @

Comment: How big is your table likely to get to? All these techniques are only really suitable for small tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a case for that:

```
... where @itemId is null or dataId = @itemId ...
```

Or:

```
... where isnull(@itemId, dataId) = dataId ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Case When @ItemId Is Not Null And dataId = itemId Then 1 Else 0 End = 0
```

If dataId is not nullable, then you can simplify it to:

```
dataId = Coalesce(@ItemId, dataId)
```

Or using a Case expression

```
dataId = Case When @ItemId Is Null Then itemId Else dataId End
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT dataId = CASE WHEN @itemId IS NOT NULL THEN @itemId 
        ELSE dataId END
 FROM YourTable
```